# JaCoCo coverage report setups(exclude test classes)

Tags: java, ant, jacoco

Im generating a jacoco coverage report using the following target :

```
   <target name="report" depends="test">

            <!-- This task needs the collected execution data and ... -->
            <executiondata>
                <file file="${result.exec.file}" />
            </executiondata>

            <!-- the class files and optional source files ... -->
            <structure name="JaCoCo Ant Example">
                <classfiles>
                    <fileset dir="${result.classes.dir}" />
                </classfiles>
                <sourcefiles encoding="UTF-8">
                    <fileset dir="${src.dir}" >
                    <exclude name="**/*Test*.class"/>
                    </fileset>  
                </sourcefiles>
            </structure>

            <!-- to produce reports in different formats. -->
            <html destdir="${result.report.dir}" />
            <csv destfile="${result.report.dir}/report.csv" />
            <xml destfile="${result.report.dir}/report.xml" />
        </jacoco:report>
    </target>
```

The problem is that the report takes into account the code from unit tests and I consider this fact a mistake. This way, your line coverage percent and instruction coverage will be artificially increased(because test lines are considered 100% covered) and report correctness is pretty affected. I tried to add this tag

```
<exclude name="**/*Test*.class"/
```

under fileset tag, hoping that testClasses will be excluded, but it doesnt works. Do you have any ideas for my problem? I want to avoid programmatically 
report modification. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to exclude the Test class files from the `classfiles` fileset:

```
<structure name="JaCoCo Ant Example">
        <classfiles>
            <fileset dir="${result.classes.dir}">
                <exclude name="**/*Test*.class"/>
            </fileset>
        </classfiles>
        <sourcefiles encoding="UTF-8">
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}" />
        </sourcefiles>
</structure>
```

See [documentation](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html):

> "Note that the classfiles and sourcefiles elements accept any Ant resource collection. Therefore also filtering the class file set is possible and **allows to narrow the scope of the report**, for example:

```
<classfiles>
    <fileset dir="classes">
        <include name="org/jacoco/examples/important/**/*.class"/>
    </fileset>
</classfiles>
```

This is because the actual report is done from the `classfiles`. The `sourcefiles` are there to include highlighted source code in the report - as of course the human eye can't read compiled code.

Again from the documentation:

> **classfiles**: Container element for Ant resources and resource
>      collections that can specify Java class files, archive files (jar,
>      war, ear etc. or Pack200) or folders containing class files. Archives
>      and folders are searched recursively for class files.
>
> **sourcefiles**:
>      **Optional container element** for Ant resources and resource collections
>      that specify corresponding source files. If source files are
>      specified, **some report formats include highlighted source code**.
>      Source files can be specified as individual files or as source
>      directories.

Comment: When the above mentioned change is done to `build.xml`, the excluded class still be part of report with `0%` coverage or is the excluded class or package completed removed and not part of report? Appreciate your help.